# Android WebView leaves space for scrollbar

Tags: android, android-webview

In my `WebView`, I have some block elements that have a background color (different than white). However, the background color does not go *all the way across the sky*.. um, screen. Instead, it leaves a small white strip to the right, for where the scrollbar would go. Now, I want the scrollbars to appear only when scrolling (and fade away once the user has finished scrolling). I tried:

```
android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" (and all other options)
```

Also, my HTML contains the following in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

So that it doesn't allow zooming and doesn't zoom out by default.

However, I can't figure out how to get rid of the white strip. Any ideas?

Comment: An obvious (but bad) solution is to wrap the `WebView` in a `ScrollView` and set `scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"` on that.

Comment: Also, my current solution is `android:scrollbars="none"` which permanently hides the scrollbars (and also the white area). This is not optimal, however.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Battled this one as well. Found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/716d7d4f9ac23ba3/0b7b446d5ee71ac5?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=remove+Webview+scroll+margin#0b7b446d5ee71ac5).

Looks like you were dead on with `android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"`, except that because of some bug it doesn't function right when defined in XML. It works right if you use:

```
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Annoying.

Comment: While we're on the topic, the same is true of the background color for WebViews. You have to use webView.setBackgroundColor(...) or it won't actually apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setVerticalScrollbarOverlay (boolean overlay)
```

Since: API Level 1
Specify whether the vertical scrollbar has overlay style.
Parameters
overlay TRUE if vertical scrollbar should have overlay style.